# Не понял асинхронность JavaScript

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, promise

Есть две асинхронные функции:

```
async function a() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
         console.log(`${i} (a)`);
    }
}

async function b() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
         console.log(`${i} (b)`);
    }
}
```

и функция `c`, вызывающая функции `a` и `b`:

```
function c() {
    a();
    b();
}
```

Если вызвать функцию `c`, то выводом будет последовательное выполнение функции `a` (все 10000 итераций), затем функции `b`.

Если функции `a` и `b` изменить таким образом:

```
async function a() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
             console.log(`${i} (a)`);
         }
         resolve();
     });
 }

 async function b() {
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
         for (var i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
              console.log(`${i} (b)`);
         }
         resolve();
    });
}
```

То результат останется прежним. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы их выводы смешались, чтобы выводилось условно

- ...
- 1112 (a)
- 1112 (b)
- 1113 (a)
- 1114 (a)
- 1113 (b)
- ...

А не

- ...
- 9999 (a)
- 10000 (a)
- 0 (b)
- 1 (b)
- ...

Как сделать это правильно и можно ли вообще?

Comment: Нельзя, javascript однопоточный

Comment: @andreymal и что тогда называется асинхронностью?

Comment: То, что на долгих операциях ожидания чего-нибудь (например, ответа от сервера) функция может передавать управление другим функциям, возвращая промисы или используя await, чтобы процессор не простаивал. В ваших циклах нет ни того, ни другого, они не отдают управление пока не пройдут все 10000 итераций

Comment: @andreymal спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript однопоточный, и асинхронные функции сами решают, когда приостановить работу и передать управление другим функциям, с помощью `await`. Циклы в функциях никто никогда не прервёт, пока сама функция не решит, что цикл можно прервать.

```js
async function a() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(`${i} (a)`);
    // Возвращаем выполнение браузеру, чтобы он повыполнял другие задачи
    // (например, цикл в b)
    await null;
  }
}

async function b() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(`${i} (b)`);
    // Возвращаем выполнение браузеру, чтобы он повыполнял другие задачи
    // (например, цикл в a)
    await null;
  }
}

function c() {
  a().then(() => console.log('a отработал'));
  b().then(() => console.log('b отработал'));
}

c();
```

Вариант, когда цикл передаёт управление другим задачам не каждый раз, а через несколько итераций:

```js
async function a() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(`${i} (a)`);
    if (i % 3 === 2) await null;
  }
}

async function b() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
     console.log(`${i} (b)`);
     if (i % 3 === 2) await null;
  }
}

function c() {
  a().then(() => console.log('a отработал'));
  b().then(() => console.log('b отработал'));
}

c();
```

Или пример с асинхронной обёрткой над `setTimeout`:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function a() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(`${i} (a)`);
    // Спим полсекунды, чтобы поработал кто-то ещё
    await sleep(500);
  }
}

async function b() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
     console.log(`${i} (b)`);
     // Спим четверть секунды для разнообразия
     await sleep(250);
  }
}

function c() {
  a().then(() => console.log('a отработал'));
  b().then(() => console.log('b отработал'));
}

c();
```

Comment: (я не знаю, почему `await null` вообще работает, но оно работает)

Comment: это же JS, здесь все этим и объясняется :D

Comment: _я не знаю, почему await null вообще работает_ - [_If the value is not a Promise, it converts the value to a resolved Promise, and waits for it._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: @Grundy спс кэп, но если Promise уже resolved, то зачем передавать управление кому-то? Можно было бы взять значение сразу, но почему-то этого не делается

Comment: так работает await ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy но вроде бы ничто не мешает сделать его работающим по-другому ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Если только в какой-нибудь спецификации это прямым текстом не запрещено

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы вывод мог перемешиваться, **каждая из итерация тоже должна быть асинхронной**.

Например используя [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) и [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

```js
async function a() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(console.log(`${i} (a)`))));
  }
}

async function b() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(console.log(`${i} (b)`))));
  }
}

function c() {
  a();
  b();
}

c();
```